# Circular data problem for Kalman filter

Tags: trigonometry, control-theory, angle, kalman-filter

I've been trying to implement a Kalman filter to get estimates of current heading (angle) of a vehicle by performing a sensor data fusion (GPS + IMU).

The GPS sensor provides heading information $\left<-180^o,180^o\right)$ with rather significant uncertainties ($\pm5^{o}$), while the IMU has a really small error ($\pm0.2^{o}$) but has a constant dynamic drift of $0.5^{o}/min$. IMU output data also covers the same range as GPS, i.e. $\left<-180^o,180^o\right)$

The IMU can be mounted in any orientation regarding magnetic north, thus initially the difference between IMU and GPS measurements can have every value in range $\left<0^o,360^o\right)$.

Thanks to the data fusion we can have IMU constancy and low noise corrected by GPS true heading.

The data fusion process is as follows:

```
                                                                         +
IMU_angle ---------+----------+-------------------------------------------> fusion output
                   |          |                                                ^ -
                   |          |                                                |
                   |          +---> process noise ------> kalman filter -------+
                   |+                                         ^
            -      v                                          |
GPS_angle ---> heading diff ------> measurement noise --------+
```

After few simulations I got rather positive results but I have a problem with how to deal with circular data. When GPS and/or IMU oscillates around $\pm180^{o}$, the heading difference between consecutive samples can jump to big values (close to $360^o$) and Kalman does not adapt quickly (which is obvious).

How should I deal with such issue?

For the sake of clarity (pseudo-code):

````
Q = 0.013   # process noise covariance
R = 8.346   # measurement noise covariance
x = 0       # initial conditions
P = Q

heading_diff[i] = -gps_heading[i] + imu_heading[i])

# prediction phase
P = P + Q;
# correction phase
K = P / (P + R)
x = x + K * (heading_diff[i] - x)
P = (1 - K) * P;

fusion_output[i] = imu_heading[i] - x
```
````

Comment: Not sure if I understand everything that you wrote, but, of course, if you allow some discontinuous stuff, you'll get problems at the discontinuity point. So, you have to teach your program that when the predictor and the observation are too far apart (jumping over $\pm 180$), you have to adjust the predictor by adding or subtracting 360 before taking the weighted average in the Kalman filter. That should take care of it, unless I misunderstood your setup.

Comment: @fedja Yes, but how can I distinguish between jumps over ±180 (so when the orientation oscillates around ±180 point) and sudden real turns (like from -179 through 0 to 179)? For my program these are consecutive measurements and I really do not know whether there was almost 360 turn or there are oscillations around ±180 (we assume that two consecutive samples are -179 and 179).

Comment: You cannot. If you have discrete time measurements and the vehicle manages a sudden real turn from -179 to 179 between two measurements, your direction indicator will just show a small change and that is normal; nobody will blame you for that. After all, how do you know that a vehicle that moves in the same direction doesn't really make a few 360 degree turns between every two observations? That is a problem of insufficient sampling frequency, not of software processing.

Comment: Thanks @fedja, indeed, you are right!

Answer (score 1):

not sure this is still relevant, but we deal with these kinds of problems in our recently published paper that allows you to apply a Kalman-filter like algorithm to circular problems (the circular Kalman filter [1] see example 5). Basically, if your data is circular, then conflicting observations (e.g. 180 deg apart) will lead to qualitatively very different behavior than using a "standard" Kalman filter - you can deal with this nonlinearity that by considering a vector addition in 2D on the level of the sufficient statistics. Specifically, this extreme case won't affect your current estimate, but will reduce your estimate's certainty, such that subsequent observations can make up for that "conflict".

[1] Kutschireiter, Rast & Drugowitsch. 2022. “Projection Filtering with Observed State Increments with Applications in Continuous-Time Circular Filtering.” IEEE Transactions on Signal Processing. https://doi.org/10.1109/TSP.2022.3143471. Publicly available version: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.09650.pdf